# Launch4J wrapped jar produces JNILibLoaderBase errors

Tags: java, jogl, jni

I created an executable jar file bundled with JOGL, then wrapped the jar into a windows executable using Launch4j in order to pass runtime java parameters. If I run the jar from a command prompt I get no errors. If instead I run the Launch4J executable I get the errors shown below, but the application nevertheless runs properly, displaying the correct graphics. So, the problem seems to lie with the Launch4J executable and not the executable jar.

Is there someway to prevent the errors that only occur when running the Launch4J executable?

```
JNILibLoaderBase: Caught IllegalArgumentException: No Jar name in <jar:file:/C:/temp/BombsightApp20231130.exe!/jogamp/common/Debug.class>
JNILibLoaderBase: Caught IllegalArgumentException: No Jar name in <jar:file:/C:/temp/BombsightApp20231130.exe!/jogamp/nativewindow/Debug.class>
JNILibLoaderBase: Caught IllegalArgumentException: No Jar name in <jar:file:/C:/temp/BombsightApp20231130.exe!/jogamp/nativewindow/Debug.class>
JNILibLoaderBase: Caught IllegalArgumentException: No Jar name in <jar:file:/C:/temp/BombsightApp20231130.exe!/jogamp/nativewindow/Debug.class>
```